# length of data to decrypt is invalid rijndael c# sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, encryption, aes, rijndael

I am trying to encrypt / decrypt sensitive data such as SSN, the encryption process goes fine, saving in DB looks good too, retrieval looks good too, but when I am on the last step to decrypt the data I am getting error message: length of data to decrypt is invalid.

I created a SQL Server table for testing which has one column to hold the data, of `varbinary` type with size of 500.

This is how the data looks like in the table:

[image]

Now here is whole code in C# which is used to encrypt the data, insert in the db, get the last record (test) and decrypt. As I said the error happens on the last step in the decryption step:

Encryption Step

```
 public byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText)
 {
             // Check arguments. 
             if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                 throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");           
             byte[] encrypted;
             // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
             // with the specified key and IV. 
             using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
             {
                 rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
                 rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                 string keyStr = "cGFzc3dvcmQAAAAAAAAAAA==";
                 string ivStr = "cGFzc3dvcmQAAAAAAAAAAA==";
                 byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
                 byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);
                 rijAlg.Key = keyArr;
                 rijAlg.KeySize = 256;
                 rijAlg.BlockSize = 128;
                 rijAlg.IV = ivArr;

                 // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
                 ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

                 // Create the streams used for encryption. 
                 using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                 {
                     using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                     {
                         using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                         {
                             //Write all data to the stream.
                             swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                         }
                         encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                         SaveData(encrypted);
                     }
                 }
            }
             // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream. 
             return encrypted;
         }
```

Saving data to database

```
public void SaveData(byte[] cipherText) {
   string queryStmt = "INSERT INTO TestSSN(SSN) VALUES(@Content)";

   using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
   using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con))
   {
      SqlParameter param = _cmd.Parameters.Add("@Content", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
      param.Value = cipherText;

      _con.Open();
      _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      _con.Close();
   }
   GetSSNData(1); }
```

Getting data from database

```
public byte[] GetSSNData(int id)
{
    byte[] cipherData = new byte[500];
    string queryStmt = "SELECT SSN FROM TestSSN WHERE ID=7";

    using (SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStmt, _con))
    {              
          _con.Open();
          SqlDataReader rdr = _cmd.ExecuteReader();

          if (rdr.HasRows)
          {
              while (rdr.Read())
              {
                    cipherData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rdr[0].ToString());
              }
          }
          _con.Close();
    }
    string roundtrip = DecryptStringFromBytes(cipherData);          
    return cipherData;
}
```

Trying to decrypt the data(you will notice two different ways for decryption here, but I'll get the same message for both of them)

```
 static string DecryptStringFromBytes(byte[] cipherText)
 {
     // Check arguments. 
     if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");           

     // Declare the string used to hold 
     // the decrypted text. 
     string plaintext = null;

     // Create an RijndaelManaged object 
     // with the specified key and IV. 
     using (RijndaelManaged rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
     {
         rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
         rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
         string keyStr = "cGFzc3dvcmQAAAAAAAAAAA==";
         string ivStr = "cGFzc3dvcmQAAAAAAAAAAA==";
         byte[] ivArr = Convert.FromBase64String(keyStr);
         byte[] keyArr = Convert.FromBase64String(ivStr);
         rijAlg.Key = keyArr;
         rijAlg.KeySize = 256;
         rijAlg.BlockSize = 128;
         rijAlg.IV = ivArr;
         // Create a decrytor to perform the stream transform.
         ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijAlg.CreateDecryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);

         byte[] decryptedText = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
         string decrpyted = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedText);          

         // Create the streams used for decryption. 
         using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
         {
             using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
             {
                 using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                 {
                     //  byte[] decryptedText = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(cipherText, 0, cipherText.Length);
                     // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream 
                     // and place them in a string.
                     plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     return plaintext;
   }
```

Advices more then welcome, I've been battling with the decryption whole day.

Thanks, Laziale

Comment: The first way to debug this problem is to remove the database code entirely. Can you encrypt data and then decrypt it successfully?

Answer (score 0):

Check the place where you read your data from DB:

```
cipherData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rdr[0].ToString());
```

If `rdr[0]` is a `byte` array I don't think that you will get the string of bytes, probably you will get "System.Byte[]". And if you will get "0xFFAA" - `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` will not give you a byte array with { 0xFF, 0xAA } data. You should use [SqlDataReader.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getbytes.aspx) to read this data.

Also I want to remind you that SSN is sensitive information. You should inform your users that you are going to save this information. If you need this information just to verify identity - you can use last 4 digits or hash. Please consider to not save SSN if you don't have real justification for this.